# Pulling XML data from SQL Server to be parsed into JSON formatting problems in C#

Tags: c#, sql, xml, json

I'm using SQLCommand in C# to run SQL against a local machine which will output XML.  The SQL code looks like this:

```
"SELECT 
   ' '                          AS 'ItemsCount', 
   ' '                          AS 'Shipping', 
   ' '                          AS 'Fee', 
   ' '                          AS 'ShippingPrc', 
   ' '                          AS 'FeeType', 
   ' '                          AS 'FeeTaxPrc', 
 //many lines of SQL omitted
 FROM   im_item 
   JOIN ps_doc_lin 
     ON im_item.item_no = ps_doc_lin.item_no 
   JOIN  ps_doc_hdr 
     ON ps_doc_hdr.doc_id = ps_doc_lin.doc_id 
   JOIN ar_cust 
   ON ar_cust.cust_no = ps_doc_hdr.cust_no 
 WHERE  ps_doc_hdr.tkt_dt = (SELECT Max(tkt_dt) //I select Max(tkt_dt) here because this program will run right after a customer has completed checkout.  I want to get the most recent ticket (i.e. the ticket just rang up)
                        FROM   ps_doc_hdr) 
 FOR xml path ('Receipt')";
```

This has been working but I recently discovered a fatal flaw.  If in the database a customer has purchased multiple items, the XML output from SQL Server will be an XML file with that customer's information repeated for each item purchased.  If I parse the XML output in C# it can't be done, the output results in multiple root elements.   I suspect that the JOIN of the various tables is causing this but I am having to pull a variety of data from SQL and I need these joins to get to what I need.

I tried to do something similar to this:

```
   ' '                          AS 'Total', 
   ' '                          AS 'InvcHdrRcptStatus', 
   ' '                          AS 'InvcHdrRcptType', 
   ' '                          AS 'Cashier', 
   ' '                          AS 'DocDate', 
   ' '                          AS 'InvcNum', 
   (SELECT      ps_doc_lin.sls_rep           AS 'Clerk'
                    FROM PS_DOC_LIN
                    WHERE PS_DOC_LIN.DOC_ID = PS_DOC_HDR.DOC_ID
                    FOR XML PATH ('Item')) as Items, 
   (SELECT     ar_cust.cust_no              AS 'BillToCustNumber', 
   ' '                          AS 'BillToCustCompany', 
   ar_cust.fst_nam              AS 'BillToFName', 
   ar_cust.lst_nam              AS 'BillToLName', 
   ar_cust.salutation           AS 'Customer/Name/Title', 
   ar_cust.adrs_1               AS 'BillToAddr1', 
   ar_cust.adrs_2               AS 'BillToAddr2', 
   ' '                          AS 'BillToAddr3', 
   ar_cust.zip_cod              AS 'BillToZip', 
   ' '                          AS 'BillToInfo1', 
   ' '                          AS 'BillToInfo2', 
   ' '                          AS 'BillToPhone1', 
   ' '                          AS 'BillToPhone2', 
   ar_cust.phone_1              AS 'ShipToPhone1', 
   ar_cust.phone_2              AS 'ShipToPhone2' FROM AR_CUST WHERE AR_CUST.CUST_NO = PS_DOC_HDR.CUST_NO FOR XML PATH ('Customer'), TYPE) as Customers,
```

I nested the JOIN into another select.  While this did work, it didn't format correctly when converted to JSON.  The output looks like this:

```
{"Receipt":{ ......//omitted data
 ,"Customer":{"Name: {"title":"Mr."}}
```

My intended output would have all of the data organized inside of {"Receipt": without the use of another {.  Similar to this:

```
    "Receipt" : {
    "InvcHdrNotes" : ""
    "Tax" : ""
    "TaxPrc" : ""
    "DiscPrc" : ""
    "Discount" : ""
    "InvcComment1" : ""
    "InvcComment2" : ""
}
```

The "Receipt" is a subsection of a much larger JSON file.  However, this flaw will be replicated (I assume so) for the remainder of the data I need to get since I will need JOIN for those as well.  I have tried using both Jayrock and Newtonsoft.Json but both have this issue.

My Goal XML output would be:

```
<Receipt>
<InvcHdrNotes> </InvcHdrNotes>
<Tax>Y</Tax>
<Clerk>MGR</Clerk>
<BillToCustNumber>1000</BillToCustNumber>
<BillToCustCompany> </BillToCustCompany>
<BillToFName>Bill</BillToFName>
<BillToLName>Baker</BillToLName>
<Customer>
  <Name>
    <Title>Mr.</Title>
  </Name>
</Customer>
<BillToAddr1>1426 Millstream Parkway</BillToAddr1>
<BillToAddr3> </BillToAddr3>
<BillToZip>38120</BillToZip>
<BillToInfo1> </BillToInfo1>
<BillToInfo2> </BillToInfo2>
<ShipToCustNumber>1000</ShipToCustNumber>
<ShipToCustCompany> </ShipToCustCompany>
<ShipToFName>Bill</ShipToFName>
<ShipToLName>Baker</ShipToLName>
<ShipToTitle>Mr.</ShipToTitle>
<ShipToAddr1>1426 Millstream Parkway</ShipToAddr1>
<ShipToZip>38120</ShipToZip>
</Receipt>
```

I get this output with the SQL code above but the identical information is repeated after the  which throws the exception I mentioned.

Is this even possible or is this a fatal design flaw?  If it isn't possible, I am unsure of how to complete this task.  Thank you.

Comment: Just a suggestion: it seems that you're asking about XML to JSON transformation.  That has nothing to do with SQL!  How about removing the SQL and adding the code that converts XML to JSON?

Comment: This does have to do with SQL.  Re-read my question, I am using Jayrock and Newtonsoft.Json to serialize which are both well known and available.  The problem isn't so much to do with the XML -> JSON, its the XML output from the SQL code having multiple root elements thereby throwing an XmlException when loaded with doc.LoadXML(xml).  Not to mention improperly formatted XML means improperly formatted JSON, GIGO.

Comment: If the problem is in the XML generated by SQL Server.  Post what you'd like the query to return, and strip out the JSON stuff.  You could even set up an example on http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: If you've got multiple root elements, why not just wrap them in a single root element using basic string-manipulation and file-IO routines?

Comment: I have added my intended XML that I would like the query to return.  The query currently will return that XML but repeated the same number of times as the number of items the customer purchased, raising the "Multiple root elements" exception when handled with the XMLDocument class.

Comment: @ekolis I would like to avoid string manipulation if possible.  I'd ideally like to have the query output be correct but if I can't find an alternative, I'll use string-manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're serializing each row returned to the same XML - so you would end up with multiple root elements. You need to serialize the List itself.

So you'd end up with:

```
<Receipts>
  <Receipt>
    ...
  </Receipt>
  <Receipt>
    ...
  </Receipt>
</Receipts>
```